# Why is Growl showing redundant notifications for Keka?

Tags: growl

Whenever I carry out an action in Keka, such as extraction or compression, I receive three Growl notifications. All are identical, but only one has the correct icon (Keka's icon) while the other two seem to display a missing icon.

[image: Example]

I've checked Growl and there's only one Keka entry.

I'm running Growl 1.3.3 and Keka 1.0.1 (not App Store version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be an issue with Keka not Growl, I've just updated Keka to 1.0.2 and the issue is resolved.

> Changes in version 1.0.2 (10/04/2012)
>
> - Fixed and issue with password protected rar files (Thanks to Clayman feedback) [Ticket 45]
> - Fixed double notification with Growl 1.3+ (Thanks to all the feedback to Chris and MacUpdate users!) [Ticket 42]
> - Fixed auto-close not always working (Thanks for the feedback Chris) [Ticket 41]
> - Fixed problems extracting password protected RAR files (Thanks to Clayman for the feedback) [Ticket 45]
> - Added sound customization (Thanks to Frank feedback) [Ticket 49]

[Keka defect 42](http://trac.kekaosx.com/ticket/42)